# Browsing specific day of specific year using Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

Is Google Earth capable of showing the map of the world on a certain day of a year like on July 21, 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very unlikely that Google Earth has historical imagery captured on the same day for all over the world.

To see whether that is the case for the day and the part(s) of the world you are interested there is help on how to [View a map over time](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148094?hl=en):

> Google Earth automatically displays current imagery. To see how images
> have changed over time, view past versions of a map on a timeline.